# iframe auto adjusting its height to fit to the content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have already tried some of the tips they are answered to regarding this iframe auto height problem.

Basically, what I want is auto adjusting the iframe's height dynamically, according to the height of the contents that are inside the iframe.

Here are the specific ones that I've tried.

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

[How to auto-size an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe)

[iframe Auto Adjust Height as content changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334154/iframe-auto-adjust-height-as-content-changes)

The iframe with the id #iframe needs to auto adjust is height to the content, so I inserted following codes each to the parent document, and to the iframe's body.

```
<script>
  // Resize iframe to full height
  function resizeIframe(height)
  {
// "+60" is a general rule of thumb to allow for differences in
// IE & and FF height reporting, can be adjusted as required..
document.getElementById('iframe').height = parseInt(height)+60;
  }
</script>
```

and to the iframe

```
<body onload="iframeResizePipe()">
<iframe id="helpframe" src='' height='0' width='0' frameborder='0'> </iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeResizePipe()
 {
            // What's the page height?
     var height = document.body.scrollHeight;

 // Going to 'pipe' the data to the parent through the helpframe..
 var pipe = document.getElementById('helpframe');

 // Cachebuster a precaution here to stop browser caching interfering
 pipe.src = 'http://www.foo.com/helper.html?height='+height+'&cacheb='+Math.random();

  }
</script>
```

This is the site that im having problem with : http://xefrontier.com

(if you click on the 'WALL' tab, the iframe is in there.)

Can anyone help me figuring out, why those codes won't work?
Thanks.

Comment: Set your iframe height to 100% it's only 200px right now

Comment: @zer00ne ah. yes, i adjusted the height to 100% but still no luck. i will retry some of the other tips as well, see if i missed something.

Comment: that's just one of few things needing to be changed. Do you know the CSS for `#tab-2`? The div containing the iframe is important.

Comment: @zer00ne i don't think there is set css properties for #tabs-2. but i can try giving height:100% to it. but even then, the height of the iframe won't really change.

Comment: Ok, take a look at my answer, good luck, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snippet of course is not functioning, I just put it there to fulfill the post requirements. Please read this [README.md](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBZ19upSDvMYfj8Jf2A1?p=info) and review the [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBZ19upSDvMYfj8Jf2A1?p=preview). All the details are in the [README.md](http://plnkr.co/edit/LBZ19upSDvMYfj8Jf2A1?p=info) and posted here as well.

## **README.md**

## iFrame Dynamic Height

This demo works under the Same Origin Policy, simply put, the parent children pages must be in the same location:

1. Same protocol   (http://)
2. Same sub-domain (http://app.)
3. Same domain     (http://app.domain.com)
4. Same port       (http://app.domain.com:80)

   - There's 3 children pages at varying heights.

     - iFrm1,html
     - iFrm2.html
     - iFrm3.html
   - Preparing layout and iframe attributes are important when we are going to control iframes.

     - The first step is done already when we established where exactly the parent and children pages are by fulfilling the requirements of the Same Origin Policy.

#### CSS:

```
/* Outer Container */

#iSec {
  width: 100vw;  /* As wide as your screen */
  height: 100vh; /* As tall as your screen */
  display: table;/* Will behave like a table */
}


/* iFrame Wrappers */

.jFrame {
   position: relative; /* As a non-static element, any descendants can be easily positioned. */
   max-height: 100%; /* Being flexible is important when dealing with dynamic content. */
   max-width: 100%; /* see above */
   overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollbars will appear when height exceeds the viewport (your screen)*/
   display: table-cell; /* Will behave like a table-cell
}

/* iFrames */

iframe {
   position: absolute; /* Easily positioned within it's parent (`.jFrame`)*/
   width: 100%; /* Set the iFrames' attribute as well */
   height: 100%; /* Set the iFrames' attribute as well */

   top: 0;  /* Streches iframes' edges */
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

#### iFrame:

```
<iframe id="iFrm1" src="iFrm1.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The majority of the code I borrowed and modified is from 
this [site](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/)

// Collect all iframes into a NodeList, convert to an array, then call iFrmHt(), and pass on the ids of each iFrame.

```
function loadiFrames() {
  var iFrmList = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
  var iFrmArray = Array.prototype.map.call(iFrmList, function(obj) {
    var ID = obj.id;
    iFrmHt(ID);
  });
}
```

// Reference the Document of the target iFrame

```
function iFrmHt(ID) {
  var iFrm = document.getElementById(ID);
  var iDoc = iFrm.contentDocument || iFrm.contentWindow.document;
  var iHt = function(iDoc) {
    if (!iDoc) {
      iDoc = document;
    }
    var iKid = iDoc.body;
    var iRoot = iDoc.documentElement;
```

// Determine iFrame's child page-- height with several different methods to measure.

```
    var iHt = Math.max(iKid.scrollHeight, iKid.offsetHeight,
      iRoot.clientHeight, iRoot.scrollHeight, iRoot.offsetHeight);
    return iHt;
  }
```

// Change the height of the iFrame

```
  iFrm.style.height = iHt + 'px';
  console.log('iFrame: ' + iFrm.id);
  console.log('height: ' + iHt(iDoc));
}
```

// If you load on window load, there shouldn't be any timeouts from the iFrames.

```
window.onload = loadiFrames;
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iFrame Dynamic Height</title>
  <style>
    #iSec {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: table;
    }
    .jFrame {
      position: relative;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="iSec">
    <div id="i1" class="jFrame">
      <iframe id="iFrm1" src="iFrm1.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="jFrame">
      <iframe id="iFrm2" src="iFrm2.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="jFrame">
      <iframe id="iFrm3" src="iFrm3.html" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
    function loadiFrames() {
      var iFrmList = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
      var iFrmArray = Array.prototype.map.call(iFrmList, function(obj) {
        var ID = obj.id;
        iFrmHt(ID);
      });
    }

    function iFrmHt(ID) {
      var iFrm = document.getElementById(ID);
      var iDoc = iFrm.contentDocument || iFrm.contentWindow.document;
      var iHt = function(iDoc) {
        if (!iDoc) {
          iDoc = document;
        }
        var iKid = iDoc.body;
        var iRoot = iDoc.documentElement;
        var iHt = Math.max(iKid.scrollHeight, iKid.offsetHeight,
          iRoot.clientHeight, iRoot.scrollHeight, iRoot.offsetHeight);
        return iHt;
      }
      iFrm.style.height = iHt + 'px';
      console.log('iFrame: ' + iFrm.id);
      console.log('height: ' + iHt(iDoc));
    }

    window.onload = loadiFrames;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another user posted this question and solution on StackOverflow a number of years ago.

[Full-screen iframe with a height of 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/full-screen-iframe-with-a-height-of-100)

This approach uses CSS instead of JS to set the dimensions of the IFRAME.