# iframe auto height doesn't work properly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I was looking for a solution for auto height adjusting depending on the contents that are inside the iframe, and this seems like it's working on chrome.

But for some reason, if i wait for the site to completely load, and then click on the '**Wall**' tab on the main page, the iframe contents are not visible, as the height is set for '4px'.

Again, if you click on the **wall** tab while it's loading, or before it gets load, it works perfectly fine.

I'm guessing it has to do with the source.
The site I'm having problem with is here : http://xefrontier.com/

could anyone tell me why this phenomenon is happening?

and this is the source:

```
  function resizeIframe(obj){
 obj.style.height = 0;
 obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }

 function getDocHeight(doc) {
doc = doc || document;
// stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(id) {
var iframe_board = document.getElementById(id);
var doc = iframe_board.contentDocument? iframe_board.contentDocument: 
    iframe_board.contentWindow.document;
iframe_board.style.visibility = 'hidden';
iframe_board.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
// IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
iframe_board.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
iframe_board.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

document.getElementById('iframe_board').onload = function() { // Adjust the Id accordingly
setIframeHeight(this.id);
}
```

Comment: Hi @MarkKang make sure that the container that holds the iframe has `overflow-x:hidden` and `overflow-y: auto or scroll` the [demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35740331/2813224) I provided you was tested with Firefox PC are you using a Mac? Btw, if the parameter was setup correctly for`docHeight(x)` that 4 should add numerically and not concat.

Comment: hey @zer00ne i haven't exactly tried your coding, but i think i'd give it a go. and yes im a mac user.

Comment: I knew it, ok instead calling function` resizeIframe` on the iframe load event, trigger later at `window.onload = resizeIframe;`  do not add the "`()'" at the end of expression. Place that at the very end of script tag.

Comment: i guess it's working! thanks.

Comment: Your'e welcome, sir. I should answer because it took me days to figure that out.

Comment: @zer00ne sure. thanks. looking forward to seeing you again. :p

Comment: I posted the answer, so whenever you have the time to accept. Likewise, sir.

Comment: um, @zer00ne, i must have touched something on my website, i think it's most likely the css position attribute. but do you happen to know why the #frame_wall now  for some reason resize it's height to fit to the height of the parent's screen resolution height on the wall tab? http://xefrontier.com/

Comment: P.S.or rather not resize anything at all? (no height value) and since im asking a question, one more : how can i apply the same js script to another one (duplicate) as well? seems like, it only works for a single iframe, is there a chance i can apply for both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105408/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-mark-kang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for OP's issue is as follows:

- A function that interacts with iframes works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

  - **STOP** If there is ever a problem with Firefox and Chrome is ok with interacting with iframes, then consider if this occurs in a PC, Mac, or both.
  - Chances are it's going to be Mac and it's *wonderful* relationship with Firefox (note: sarcasm cannot not be expressed very well on keyboard).
- If the problem is isolated to the Mac running Firefox, then you can do the following to fix it 88.4% of the time.

  1. Locate any event handlers that are listening for the load event on iframes:

     - ex. `<iframe src="domain.com" onload="eventHandler()"></iframe>`

       REMOVE=================^-------===THIS===------^.
  2. Disable/remove them.
  3. At the very end of your `</script>` block add this:

     ex.  `window.onload = eventHandler;`

  NOTE  ===================^=^ -DO NOT ADD `()` at the end of function

Firefox Mac has many different issues unique onto itself, some by design. One of those bugs is it's inability to acknowledge an iframe's existence after it's been loaded. Firefox Mac will deal with iframes after everything else has been loaded. This is just my observation from experience.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to resize iframe height

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = (obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
</script>
```

and in iframe tag

```
  <iframe src="somepage.php" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

Comment: i have tried the code you gave me here, but still no luck :( try it out on my live website : http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/ just wait for a few sec to fully load (the orange circle disappears) and then click on the wall tab.

Comment: remove height="100%" in the iframe tag ,style="height: 0px;"

Comment: in case you didn't notice this, it's that javascript that's giving the height:0 to the iframe. i got rid of the rest from the styling, and yet there is just no luck. any solution you can think of?

Comment: are yu loading the frame contents using ajax ?

Comment: checkout this page working in firefix https://www.remotraining.com/schedules.html