# Facebook page add extra height below footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, facebook

I have created my web page to https://www.gympages.net/adnankhalid/fitness-club-9-footer/ but its adding some extra height bellow footer on facebook page. "https://www.facebook.com/Eddie-Khokhar-1258738947491895/app/1162443360455325/"

I want to ask if some one can please help me out how can i remove this 21px height bellow all content in footer. I have lots of templates i need dynamic solution to help this out.

I and using "FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();" function

Comment: Welcome to SO, questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: the problem is the `iframe`, did you have access to it ? if so just change the `height` to fit your page

Answer (score 0):

Height of your iframe is set to 1967px. That is what is creating the space below the footer. Size it to arround 1500 or so.

Comment: I am using "FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();" function to giving height to iFrame. Some time its give perfect height some time 21px extra and some time 1977px. But I can't give fixed height to each of them.

Comment: See if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334154/iframe-auto-adjust-height-as-content-changes